# Check whether an application is running?

Tags: c#, process

I want to check if a program is running or not.
For example, check that the program (notepad) is running.

I tried this code :

```cs
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("App name");
if (pname.Length != 0) { 
   //run 
}
```

I want to check. But when the burst is checking, the program (app name) stops. And whenever the checking operation is completed, the program (app name) starts

```cs
public void BS() 
    bool key = true;
    while (key) {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("appname");
        if (pname.Length != 0) {
            textBox1.Text += "run";
        } else {
            key = false;
            textBox1.Text += "stop";
        }
    }
}
```

The appname.exe program should continue to work in any case, but when I put this in my form to check appname.exe the appname.exe program stops.

Whenever the while cycle is stopped, appname.exe starts up.

Comment: When using while loops for a "long" period, in this case when until `key = false`, you should consider adding a "pause" in your loop. This will prevent the CPU from blasting to 100% and consume too much resources. So add `Thread.Sleep(10);` at the bottom of the while loop to see if that has any positive effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it with the name:

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
if (pname.Length == 0)
  MessageBox.Show("nothing");
else
  MessageBox.Show("run");
```

You can loop all process to get the ID for later manipulation:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
   Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is going into the infinite loop which might causing the application stop and start.

Try putting some thread sleep between checking again.

```
public void BS()
{
    bool key = true;
    while (key)
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("appname");
        if (pname.Length != 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text += "run";
        }
        else
        {
            key = false;
            textBox1.Text += "stop";
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //For 1 Second
    }
}
```